# Android - PX to DP - Wrong height of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am giving a layout height as 64dp in layout file and observed the mismatch in calculated and actual pixel height.

HDPI device - Calculated height - 96 pixels, Actual height: 102 pixels
XXHDPI Device - Calculated height - 192 pixels, Actual height: 204 pixels

Any one can help me understand the difference in calculated and actual height.

Comment: This isn't really an issue to worry about. It depends on the **effective** device density. We are using "normalized densities" for hour commodity. But a device might not be exactly 240 dpi (maybe it is 252 dpi) or 480 dpi (maybe it is  492 dpi).

Answer (score 2):

`mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` etc are "generalized densities". That is,  dpi groups or ranges.

From [Android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

[image]

For example two devices can have dpi values of 310 and 320 dpi respectively and fall in same group: `xhdpi`.

The calculations done by device code are using exact dpi value. While calculations based on dpi groups assume the following:

1. ldpi (low) ~120dpi
2. mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
3. hdpi (high) ~240dpi
4. xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
5. xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
6. xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

**Update:**

The following code:

```
int widthDp = 160;

Log.i("TEST", "Actual DPI: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi);

float widthDevice = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,widthDp,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Log.i("TEST", widthDp + " dip in pixels on device: " + widthDevice);
```

When run on two `hdpi` devices:

213 DPI device:

```
2164-2164/com.example.android.dpitest I/TEST﹕ Actual DPI: 213.0
2164-2164/com.example.android.dpitest I/TEST﹕ 160 dip in pixels on device: 213.0
```

And 240 DPI device:

```
2852-2852/com.example.android.dpitest I/TEST﹕ Actual DPI: 240.0
2852-2852/com.example.android.dpitest I/TEST﹕ 160 dip in pixels on device: 240.0
```

Comment: what will happen if we give a height of 160dp for `ImageView` for devices which have dpi values of 310 and 320 dpi, Will it be adjusted to 155dp in devices with 310 dpi  values

Comment: @SaiPhani No, I don't think any adjustment is made.